# GetAppSetting from Azure returning null

Tags: c#, azure, appsettings

I am developing a chatbot azure-service. It actually works, but I am having problems while trying to debug it.

I configured the bot framework emulator following the steps from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-debug-emulator

Again, it seems to work. Connection is established.

Only problem is regarding the way I have to get the appsettings to read the different API keys.

In the base code I downloaded from azure settings are read like this:

```
var qnaSubscriptionKey = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnASubscriptionKey");
var qnaKBId = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId");
```

But it always returns `null` .I changed to

```
var qnaSubscriptionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnASubscriptionKey"];
var qnaKBId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];
```

so I read the settings from the `Web.config` file.

Checking this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setting-and-reading-values-from-app-settings-json-in-net-core/ If I understood it correctly, appsettings is for .NET core applications.

My chatbot dll is using .NET 4.7.1.

Is there a way I can read the appsettings.json or should I just use the `ConfigurationManager` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 4.x projects use XML `.config` files to express application settings. And the way to access these is either to use `ConfigurationManager` or `CloudConfigurationManager`.

.NETCore makes use of `json` files to express application settings. Here are [fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration) for reading config values in .NetCore.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the base code from the template in azure is not consistent if it mixing the `Utils.GetAppSetting` in a .NET 4.x project type. I modified my code to use `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("QnASubscriptionKey")` that should be the equivalent to `Utils.GetAppSetting` in this case.